# How can I import grafana-dashboard from prometheus-operator to external grafana?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus-operator

I installed grafana to namespace `grafana` and install prometheus-operator without embedded grafana to namespace `prometheus-operator`.

How can I import the dashboard from prometheus-operator to my grafana?

Comment: how you installed it, which versions used, what you have already configured there? try to follow [Infrastructure monitoring using kube-prometheus operator](https://www.squadcast.com/blog/infrastructure-monitoring-using-kube-prometheus-operator#kube-prometheus)  - that installation works like a charm

Comment: I want to use dashboards for `grafana` from `prometheus-operator chart` in external `grafana` installed separately in another namespace.

Using the latest versions of charts